# Ncurses - "move" and its deveratives delete screen contents

Tags: c++, ncurses

I'm a newbie programmer and am currently writing a simple Ncurses application, but i faced such a problem - calling the `move` function or `mvwadch` as example cleans the window contents after the place i'm moving to.
The code is like:

```
#include <string>
#include <ncurses.h>
void function(WINDOW* win)
{
    std::string somestring = "Test";        
    waddstr(win, somestring.c_str());
    wmove(win , 0, 1);

    wrefresh(win);
}


WINDOW* win_ = initscr();
int main()
{
    function(win_);
    wgetch(win_);
    endwin();
}
```

It leaves only "T", as example, if `somestring` is "Test".

P.S. Sorry for possible bad English and c++.

Comment: That's not an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Oh, sorry, just waked up and forgotten to include the headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program doesn't wait for user input (e.g., a call to `getch`) and exits immediately without calling `endwin`.  Because ncurses initializes the terminal to *raw mode*, that leaves the terminal in *raw mode*, making the normal translation of newline to carriage-return/line-feed by your shell not work immediately (though most shells recover from this by resetting the mode back to *cooked*).  That causes some text to be overwritten since (instead of advancing to a ***newline***) the shell prompt is written on the same line as the text-message.